# Replace The Code In A Set Of Files Inside Folder By PHP

Tags: php, html, xcode, replace, directory

I have files (index.html) in a folder, these files contain the following code

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus®">
  <meta name="Author" content="">
  <meta name="Keywords" content="">
  <meta name="Description" content="">
  <title>Document</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/open.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

I want Script php looking for this code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/open.js"></script>
```

in all the files inside the folder paths and replace it with this code

```
    <script type="text/javascript"
 src="/wp-content/open.js">
</script>
```

extra information

folder name:(myhome)

folder paths:
/myhome/

/myhome/video/

/myhome/photo/

/myhome/models/

/myhome/contact/

and more...

files paths:
/myhome/index.html

/myhome/video/index.html

/myhome/photo/index.html

/myhome/models/index.html

/myhome/contact/index.html

and more...

please help me

Comment: `file_get_contents` -> `str_replace` -> `file_put_contents` ?

Comment: i don't understand.
can you make php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this solution
http://pastebin.com/wuWupgBg

and change

```
if( is_file( $path ) && substr($path, -3)=='php' && substr($path, -17) != 'ChangePHPText.php'){
```

to

```
if( is_file( $path ) && substr($path, -4)=='html' && substr($path, -17) != 'ChangePHPText.php'){
```

Answer (score 0):

mmhh, open all those files in your IDE, then search and replace \o/

OR :

```
$dir = '/myhome/';

echo 'Looking in '.$dir.' ...<br />';

$scan = scandir($dir);

foreach( $scan as $item ){

    if( is_dir($dir.$item) ){

        echo 'Looking in '.$dir.$item.' ...<br />';

        $scan_bis = scandir($dir.$item);

        if( array_key_exists('index.html', $scan_bis) ){

            $the_file = $dir.$item.'/index.html'; // im not sure if you need the trailing slash or not before index.html

            echo 'Modifying '.$the_file.' ... ';

            $file = file_get_contents($the_file);

            $file = str_replace('/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/open.js', '/wp-content/open.js', $file);

            $is_writed = file_put_contents($the_file, $file);

            if( $is_writed === FALSE ){

                echo '( FAILED )<br />';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You will just have to modify the /myhome/index.html manualy :)

Comment: thank you for help.
no work.
I have more than 200 files (index.html) inside the folder paths(myhome)

Comment: oh, you mean this code doesn't work ? .. mmhh well, then i will edit it if you confirm me. PS : if the script is in `"/myhome/"` change `$dir = "/myhome/";` by `$dir = "./";`. I think i will edit this and give you a script a little bit more complicated but it will do the work in any case, posting it tomorrow :p

Comment: thank you again
the script is in "/myhome/" and i change $dir = "/myhome/"; by $dir = "./"; 
i open mywebsite.com/myhome/replease.php
the browser print:
Looking in ./ ...
Looking in ./. ...
Looking in ./.. ...

after that i view index.html, doesn't anything changed.

replease.php contains:
<?php

$dir = './';

The rest of your code above...
?>

Comment: i founds this app (Text Crawlar).
It works the same in asking my question, but in the windows system. 
I want the same idea works on PHP in my website.

This application site:
digitalvolcano.co.uk/textcrawler.html

Comment: what is exactly the output of my code ? i don't have time to dev a fully app just for ou man soz

Comment: it searches in folders but no replace anythings.
result source code is
Looking in ./ ...<br />Looking in ./. ...<br />Looking in ./.. ...<br />Looking in ./gf ...<br />